# UK Visa for Plab 2 Financial consideration: Regular Deposits from a Sibling

Tags: united-kingdom

I’d like to appreciate the help provided by this forum. 
I’ll be applying for a visa to take the plab 2 exam and I’m not quite sure about whether or not my financial situation poses any “refusal” risks. My major concern is this: the main source of income for me is our family farm (poultry) which I run with my sister. She transfers revenue monthly to me because she handles sales and lives at home. I also work privately as a doctor, (only night calls) and earn significantly lower than I do from the farm.  Will the fact that it’s not a registered business but a farm adversely affect my situation? 
I intend to get a letter from my sister explaining the transactions, an affidavit and  a picture of the farm. Is this necessary?

Comment: Welcome, George.The site has a question and answer format, rather than a forum. Earlier answers may respond to your concerns: this [Q&A](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104) and [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42820). However, note that PLAB2  has one purpose, to work in the UK so finances are just one factor, Also take a look at the many [questions here about PLAB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=plab)

Comment: Should this really have been migrated? Taking the PLAB 2 might suggest that OP wants to work in the UK at some point, but I don’t see anything to suggest that they’ll do so immediately, or that *this* trip (or this visa application) is anything other than a short visit for the purpose of taking the exam. Unless OP makes it clear that that’s not the case this is a travel question, not an expats question.

Comment: This seems to be about the financial requirements for getting a Visa and the exam has nothing to do with that?

Comment: @ChrisH I agree with you: this should fit at TSE, as it's about a visitor visa, and where there dozens of similar questions. It may have be my comment about the purpose of the exam. When it hit the VTC off topic queue, I voted to keep it open but here it is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic and should fit at TSE.